# IBM DMC tableindex tableindex_performance table are too big

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm using IBM Data Management Console v. 3.1.9.0 and I monitor 29 DBs. Lately the IBMCONSOLE tables are getting too big (last month they've grown over 300% each).

1. table: TABLEINDEX_PERFORMANCE is > 9 GB
2. table: TABLEINDEX is > 8 GB

How to reduce this tables?

I keep only 1 week of monitored data in the DMC.

Comment: If you do not have a support contract with IBM, and if DMC pruning tool does not cover that table and no other housekeeping controls are provided, then maybe ask IBM via their comminuty?  Otherwise you have to do your own housekeeping More DMC people migt be reachable via the IBM community at this address: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datamanagement/communities/community-home/digestviewer?CommunityKey=ea909850-39ea-4ac4-9512-8e2eb37ea09a